# Added file with 'git add', but not reflected in 'git diff'

Tags: git, git-diff

I checked out OpenSSL with `git clone git://git.openssl.org/openssl.git`. I made a change to the sources, added documentation, and issued `git add doc/crypto/<file>`.

When I perform a `git diff`, the new file is not included in the changes.

How do I force Git to include the change in the diff? Or how do I create a diff with the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the path to the repo and see if that works. Try:

```
git diff [remote_name]/master
```

If you're remote is `upstream` you can do:

```
git diff upstream/master
```

Comment: `git diff master` worked like a charm. Is there a setting in Git's config that enables it all the time? That is, I want to type `git diff` and *really* get all the changes, and not some of the changes.

Comment: not that i'm aware of - i think they do this because you might have multiple remotes that you want to compare to?

Answer (score 4):

`git diff`, by default, does not show staged changes (i.e., changes that were `git add`ed). If you want to view them you'd need to use `git diff --cached`.

Comment: Interesting... `git diff --cached` only shows me the changes from the add, and not the other changes.